# Second Microphone for Stereo Recordings: Identical or Different?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, home-studio, stereo

In search for a more `spatial` and `natural` sounding recording, I thought perhaps I would add a second microphone to my existing setup (1 Rode NT1-A attached to a Marantz PMD-661 recorder) which records marvelously but only in Mono with 1 mic. I mainly want to record my voice and add spatial/room natural 3D stereo space effect.

**What do you recommend?**

A) Buy another identical Rode NT1-A

B) Buy a different second mic (e.g. a Rode NT-1000) to add a different clarity on right ear than left ear which might enhance the spatial stereo effect.

C) Something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever I've done stereo micing before I've used 2 identical mics.  However there is a technique which uses 2 different mics called [Middle Side](http://www.recording-microphones.co.uk/Mid-Side-stereo.shtml), which then needs to be decoded either through hardware or software to give normal Left-Right signals.  It's something I've often thought interesting but never had the opportunity to play with.

Comment: +1 @Phil thanks for this new insight. I had never heard of Middle Side technique. A video on your link shows the results:  http://www.recording-microphones.co.uk/Mid%20Side%20FLV/Mid%20Side2.html   However, I dont own a figure 8 mic which seems necessary here...  I am guessing the NT1000 and Nt1-A will perform very similarly...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't advise you about the Rode mics as I've never used either of them.  Maybe if you want to experiment it might be worth hiring a mic for a day and seeing how you get on with it, and if it is the effect that you want.